# Excel: Count every date in a column and give back the sum of dates (preferably in *one* formula)

Tags: excel, date, excel-formula, formula, formulas

[image]

As you will see in my picture, I do have the following problem: I want to find out whether a value in a cell of column `A` contains a date or not. In order to do so, I have used the following formula in cells `B1:B8`:

- German Excel formula: `=WENN(ISTZAHL(TAG(A1));1;0)`
- English Excel formula: `=IF(ISNUMBER(DAY(A1)),1,0)`

As you will quickly notice, it works for `B1:B6` but is faulty when it comes to `B6:B7`, etc.

So: What is wrong with that formula? Column `A` is formated as `TT.MM.JJJJ` (or `DD.MM.YYYY`) as a whole.

If that formula were to work properly, I could easily count the number of dates in column `A` using column `B`. **But:** Is there a way to do this *without* having to use column `B`, that is, checking whether a cell in `A` contains a date *and* adding it up in *one* cell with a respective formula?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check if the cell is empty before checking if it's a date:

```
=IF(A1!='', IF(ISNUMBER(DAY(A1)),1,0), '')
```

If you want the sum, you can use

```
=COUNTIF(B16:B23,">32874")
```

`32874` is the decimal representation of 1/1/1900, if you need to parse earlier dates, you can just use `1` too.

Comment: That `IF` code works perfectly fine, the `COUNTIF`, however, doesn’t. I have also tried to write the German code `=ZÄHLEWENN(A:A;">1/1/1900")` or some variations of it (`">1.1.1900"` or `">01.01.1900"`), but that did not work either.

Comment: See if that works now. Apparently it has problems converting the date to a decimal representation in the `condition`.

Comment: That, unfortunately, doesn’t work, too. It does not matter whether I’m writing `=COUNTIF(A:A,">32872")`, `=COUNTIF(A:A,">1")` or the German version of that formula.

Comment: That's weird, what Error do you get? You can try using `;` as a seperator, depends on the locale.

Comment: As an example, when I type in `=ZÄHLEWENN(A1:A2;">1")`, the result in the respective cell will be `#NAME?`.

Comment: It's `=ZÄHLENWENN(A1:A2;">1")`, there is a missing `N`. And 1/1/1900 works perfectly then ;)

Comment: @Qralnaq If this solved your problem I'd appreciate if you accept the answer :)